# blocking MPI_Scatter deadlocks

Tags: mpi

in the book Using Advanced MPI by W. Gropp et al. (page 19 on Non-blocking Collectives) it reads:

> "Any blocking collective operation on all four communicators at the same time would lead to a deadlock because of the cyclic matching ordering dependency ..."

According to the book this code would deadlock:

```
MPI_Comm comm[5]= {c_my, c_north, c_south, c_east, c_west}
for (i=0; i<5; ++i) {
  MPI_Scatter(sbf[i], ct, dt, rbf[i], ct, dt, 0, comm[i]);
}
```

I understood that MPI_Scatter is a blocking operation, thus when in the first iteration (i=0) MPI_Scatter is called it blocks afterward, and only when it is done the program's flow continues and the next iteration is executed without creating a deadlock.

I guess I am missing something? Thanks.

Comment: how were the communicators created?

Comment: The communicators include the processes in a 5-point stencil, root processes are at the center and there is overlap in the neighboring communicators

Comment: so let's assume process 1 is at the north of process 0. With a trivial `MPI_Scatter()` implementation (root sends to all non roots, non roots receive from root), then in the first iteration 0 sends to 1, and 1 sends to 0. It might deadlock since no matching receive has been posted.

Comment: I would argue the deadlock is more obvious with `MPI_Gather()`

Comment: but I understood MPI_Scatter includes both the Send and Recv in blocking versions, thus once the first MPI_Scatter finishes (i=0) everything should be sync to continue with the next MPI_Scatter (i=1)

Comment: When all the ranks call `MPI_Scatter(..., root=0, comm=c_my)`, then all the ranks send data and none receive, hence the deadlock.